# How to properly connect to SQL Server from a python script when python packages are based on github?

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, git, odbc

Suppose that due to an HTTP 403 Error it's not possible to download the packages from the PyPi repo (nor  `pip install <package>` commands) which causes me to install the `pyodbc`  by cloning the repo from Github (https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) and by running the next  `.cmd`   windows file:

```
cd "root_folder"
git activate
git clone https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc.git --depth 1
```

Note that this package is downloaded to the same root folder where my python script is, after this I try to set a connection to Microsoft SQL Server:

```
import pyodbc as pyodbc

# set connection settings 
server="servername"
database="DB1"
user="user1"
password="123"

# establishing connection to db
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+database+";UID="+user+";PWD="+password)

cursor=conn.cursor()

print("Succesful connection to sql server")
```

However, when I run the above code the next traceback error arises:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/dcleaner.py", line 47, in 
> conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+server+";DATABASE="+database+";UID="+user+";PWD="+password)
> AttributeError: module 'pyodbc' has no attribute 'connect'

Do you know how can I properly connect from a py script to a sql-server based database?

Comment: Well `https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc.git` is the **source code** of the pyodbc module, including .cpp source files, not a binary distribution. You still need to build it so as to be able to import and use it in your own Python scripts.

Comment: Why are you getting HTTP 403 Forbidden errors? Solving that problem should enable you to `pip install pyodbc` normally.

Comment: Hi, do you know where I can find the python's binary packages distributions, is it from PyPi?

Answer (score 1):

After you have cloned PYODBC

```
cd "root_folder"
git activate
git clone https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc.git --depth 1
```

On your Local Machine, Go into the cloned directory and open terminal and run below command

```
python setup.py build
```

if it errors then try to install appropriate C++ compiler *(the error might reveal this detail/ on VSCode it gave the URL to open and download, which I have shared below)* install it from here [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) - choose this one

[image]

reboot machine and run this again

```
python setup.py build    #if success then continue with below one
python setup.py install
```

after that you should be able to import and run the below from your local machine

```
import pyodbc as pyodbc
```

Comment: I still get the following error:    > Collecting setuptools>=61.0.0
  HTTP error 403 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/e3/2951/setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=a54 (from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/) (requires-python:>=3.7)
    Could not install requirement setuptools>=61.0.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/e3/251/setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=6a54 because of error 403 Client Error: BlockMedia(C)TypeExecutableCode for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/e3/251/setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: I have changed and modified my answer please read again

Comment: @AlSub please see, I have edited and changed my answer, please accept as solution, if it worked for you !!